# algorithm for even distribution of values to all processes

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, distributed

I have to write a distributed system with four processes running on four different nodes. The distributed system is supposed to work in the following way: a random number generator generates a random number at each process. The objective is to even out these values in all processes by message passing between processes. Such that process A is the server who gets the numbers from all proceses and then orders them to send a portion of their number to one or more other processes in order to even out all numbers the processes hold. For example A's count is 30, B's count is 65, C's count is 35 and D's count is 70. A computes 30+65+35+70 = 200 divided by 4 = 50. Now process A, the server, knows who has less than average and who has more than average. Now the question is how does A decide who sends what number to who? to even out the values of all processes. please note that A can't directly instruct a process to decrement or increment its count e.g. it can't send a message to B and tell it to decrement by 15 and then send another message to C and tell it to increment by 15. A must send a message to B that will tell B to decrement by 15 and then send a message to C and tell it to increment by 15 or in other words it tell B to send 15 of your count to C. Thanks in advance. Zaki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you describe is known as *distributed aggregation*. There are a number of solutions appropriate for different assumptions on the network (what nodes are connected? can messages be lost?), the function to compute (average? sum?), and so on. A good overview, with references to algorithms that you can use, can be found at http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.0725.

Comment: Thank you the I found the ring approach described in the survey paper that you provide a link to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For what I know there's not a specific *recipe* or only well define pattern to implement such distributed system (also if there's material that gives guidelines on argument, see the link at end of the question).
Here are involved various choice that will shape the final system, its scalability, how will be responsive, how will be solid, etc.

You tagged the question as language agnostic. I'm convinced that good concepts count more than technologies, but at the end the choice must be made and a system like this is too complex to be built with a language you're not more than familiar.

I would build it with C# because it's my primary development language, proceeding with techniques oriented to [agile development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development).

1. First I'll try to sketch a **macro-architectural design**, highlighting actors involved and their responsibility (but without going in too much details).
2. Then I'll try to code a first **simple prototype** that involves two nodes.
3. When the prototype works, I'll try to found **weak points** and let it work with four nodes.
4. If there are issues, iterate last point until it **satisfy requirements**.

Going much into detail, you can build it even using *raw sockets*; but to keep it simple I suggest you found your system on [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) (e.g. using the .NET BCL [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) components as basis) for communication:

1. A predefined set of `GET` message can performs synchronization between peer servers.
2. `POST` message can be used to exchange data on random numbers.

About the generation of number, it opens a completely new world. I would rely on an external service like [ANU Quantum Random Server](http://qrng.anu.edu.au/index.php) (if you can count an active Internet connection). I know you stated you've an algorithm to implement, I supplied this as an alternative (I don't know if this part can be altered or not).

As least thing, I suggest you to read [this article](http://fupeg.blogspot.it/2007/11/network-application-pattern.html) and also [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/p2p/archive/2007/03/12/writing-peer-to-peer-applications-using-net-part-1-pnrp.aspx) about *peer-to-peer* if you'll use .NET framework.

Comment: Thank you for this comment Jay. However, what I am looking for is algorithm to facilitate the even distribution as descried above. I have no worries about the implementation (or the random number generation) thanks anyways.